# How to implement Hook in Yii2?

Tags: php, json, git, yii2, hook

I have successfully setup Yii2 in my local machine. My current Yii version is 2.0.11.2. I want to use hook in my project. Here I have run composer command for installing hook. But Unable to install it.

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiike/yii2-hook "*"
```

Error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2>composer require --prefer-dist yiike/yii2-hook "*"
./composer.json has been updated
The "extra.asset-installer-paths" option is deprecated, use the "config.fxp-asse
t.installer-paths" option
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package yiike/yii2-hook * is satisfiable by yiike/yii2-hook[
dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2>
```

I am following this doc: https://packagist.org/packages/yiike/yii2-hook  (Clearly not mentioned in doc)

Alternately I have added `"yiike/yii2-hook": "*"` in my composer.json then update composer. But same error coming.

Could you please help me

**Edit:**

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "yiike/yii2-hook": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the minimun stability of your `composer.json` to the question

Comment: @SmartCoder I have edited my question. Could you please check. :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the library you are trying to install does not have any stable version available, and your `composer.json` is configured to accept on stable versions of packages

change `minimum-stability` to `dev`, and the issue should be resolved

Comment: Another error is coming when I have changed `stable` to `dev` see screenshot - https://imgur.com/AEXei7u

Comment: not surprising as the git repo does not exist anymore (if you follow the links from pakigist to the source, you will get a 404)

Comment: Yes you are right I am getting 404 also. But How to install it?

Comment: unless you can get your hands on the code from elswhere(say, directly from the author), i am afraid that this extension is gone forever

Comment: Could you please provide me any php hook tutorial. I am getting confuse about the hook :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use stable version of hook or change your
composer setting `minimum-stability` to `dev` .

OR you can use this jquery hook [Jquery Hook](https://github.com/dlds/yii2-jqhooks)

Comment: This is for  jquery. But I want to hook in PHP. I have some database functionality so I want to fetch it through `hook`

Comment: you can you your database value using php for jquery. just search on google if you don't know